# How to avoid Touches cancelled event?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitouch, touchescancelled

I have two views one beneath the another. I'm rotating the below view by touch sensing of top view. while trying to make a swipe, touches canceled event is called before touches ended event.    While moving the finger touches began and touches moved events are called , and then touches ended event is called at the last(mostly). But sometimes while trying to move slowly,touches canceled event is called stopping the touch events to occur. So i couldn't rotate view in slow speed. What may be the problem? how to avoid touches canceled event?

Note: I'm drawing some graphs in views using core-plot lib.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you are using any `UIGestureRecognizers` they automatically cancel touches to other views when they recognize their gesture.  You can turn this behavior off with the `cancelsTouchesInView` property of the recognizer.

Answer (score 5):

If your are not using UIGestureReconizer directlly, be aware of the property gestureRecognizers of the UITouch.
I have the same problem and with this code I solve it:

```
if (event.type == UIEventTypeTouches)
{
    NSSet* tmpTouches = [event  touchesForView:m_PhotoView];
    if ([tmpTouches count] == 2)
    {
        UITouch *tmpTouch1 = [[tmpTouches allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
        UITouch *tmpTouch2 = [[tmpTouches allObjects] objectAtIndex:1];
        if ((tmpTouch1 != nil)&&(tmpTouch2 != nil))
        {
            UIGestureRecognizer * tmpG;
            if ([tmpTouch1.gestureRecognizers count] > 0)
            {
                tmpG = [tmpTouch1.gestureRecognizers objectAtIndex:0];
                tmpG.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
            }
            if ([tmpTouch2.gestureRecognizers count] > 0)
            {
                tmpG = [tmpTouch2.gestureRecognizers objectAtIndex:0];
                tmpG.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
            }
            // Code ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This was perfect for what I needed as I wasn't using gestureRecognizers, and it disabled all cancel events from ruining my otherwise smooth movements. Thanks pocjoc.

Comment: I am not using gestures, but I don't understand the significance of tmpTouches count as 2 and hard coding the values of indices. Can you please explain a little more on it?

Answer (score 3):

Look out for UISwipeGestureRecognizer as well. This was causing the issue for me and is resolved once we set

```
[recognizer setCancelsTouchesInView:FALSE];
```

Answer (score 1):

If a **scroll view** is involved, *uncheck* its property content touch *Can Cancel On Scroll* in the storybord.